# How do I define absolute value of this exponent function $\sin(e^7) + 7 - 8 \sqrt{2}$

Tags: trigonometry, absolute-value

It's been while since I've studied math. Can someone please explain how to solve the absolute value of this expression without calculator.

$$
\sin(e^7) + 7 - 8 \sqrt{2}
$$

Comment: Hint: $ |\sin\theta|\le 1$ and $\sqrt2>1$.

Comment: What have you tried?  I assume all you mean is "what is the sign of this expression"?  I don't think anyone will compute $\sin (e^7)$ by hand.  But it is easy to estimate the magnitude of $7-8\sqrt 2$.

Comment: Should we assume that you want to "compute the value of", not "define absolute value of" ?

Answer (score 3):

Since $8\sqrt 2>8=7+1\ge 7+\sin e^7$, the number 
$$\sin e^7+7-8\sqrt 2$$
is negative. Therefore, its absolute value is
$$8\sqrt 2-7-\sin e^7$$